# terminating a running boost thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I currently have a boost thread as such

```
class foo
{
  private:
  boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> t;
  public:
  foo()
  {
    t = boost::make_shared<boost::thread>(&foo::SomeMethod,this);
  }
  void SomeMethod()
  {
    while(true)
    {
       .... //Does some work
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000)); //sleep for 5 seconds
    }
  }

  void stopThread()
  {
    //Elegant and instant way of stopping thread t
  }
}
```

I have read from [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#interruption_points) post that you have to define interruption points however I am not sure if I understand how that would fit in my scenario. I am looking for a safe elegant way that will ensure that thread t is terminated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't ever safely *terminate* a thread, you just need to tell it from the outside that it should stop. If you interrupt a thread, you don't know where you interrupted it and you could leave the system in an unknown state.

Instead of looping forever, you can check a variable (make sure it's thread safe though!) inside the thread's loop to see if the thread should exit. What I do in work threads is I have them wait on a condition variable, and then when there's work they wake up and do work, but when they're awake they also check the "shutdown" flag to see if they should exit.

A snippet of my code:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Manager::ThreadMain() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lock( m_work_mutex, std::defer_lock );
    while( true ) {
        lock.lock();
        while( m_work_queue.empty() && !m_shutdown ) {
            m_work_signal.wait( lock );
        }

        if( !m_work_queue.empty() ) {

            // (process work...)
            continue;
        }

        // quit if no work left and shutdown flag set.
        if( m_shutdown ) return;
    }
}
```

You could maybe get away with something like:

```
std::atomic<bool> stop_thread = false;

void SomeMethod()
{
  while( !stop_thread )
  {
    .... //Does some work
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000)); //sleep for 5 seconds
  }
}

void stopThread()
{
  stop_thread = true;

  // join thread (wait for it to stop.)
  t->join();
}
```

And let me tell you, sometimes it isn't easy to make something safely exit. A few weeks ago I had a big struggle with threaded console input. I ended up having to handle raw windows console events and translating them into keystrokes myself, just so I could simultaneously intercept my custom shutdown event.

Answer (score 0):

Use boost::thread interrupt()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>

class Foo
{
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> t;
public:
    Foo()
    {
        t = boost::make_shared<boost::thread>(&Foo::SomeMethod, this);
    }
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        std::cout << "thread starts" << std::endl;
        while(true) {
            std::cout << "." << std::endl;
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
        }
    }
    void stopThread()
    {
        t->interrupt();
        t->join();
        std::cout << "thread stopped" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    foo.stopThread();
    return 0;
}
```

Execute it

```
# g++ f.cpp -lboost_thread && ./a.out
thread starts
.
.
.
.
.
thread stopped
```